# Unity3d Local Forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move a Rigidbody forward in local coordinates, I mean, if I rotate it I want it to move in his local X axis.

I have tried this, but it moves in global coordinates:

```
Rigidbody player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
movement = movement.normalized * 2 * Time.deltaTime;
player.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
```

I don't know how to make the change to local coordinates.

Comment: Please, read tag descriptions before using them. `unity` has nothing to do with Unity game engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MovePosition works in world space, so you have to do this:

```
Rigidbody player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); // I really hope you're not doing this every frame, btw
float speed = 2f; // magic numbers are bad, move them to variables, at least
Vector3 movement = transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
player.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
```

Comment: I've tried that before, but it moves in a very weird way... it moves in circles not only forward, it kinda loops around the axis

Comment: so... I've found why it loops, the object I'm trying to move is a sphere, and I want it to rotate as it moves. Actually the complete code is with this line

`transform.RotateAround (transform.position,rotateForward,speed*Time.deltaTime);`

your suggestion works if I don't rotate my sphere

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *localPosition* instead of *position*

```
Rigidbody player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
movement = movement.normalized * 2 * Time.deltaTime;
player.MovePosition(transform.localPosition + movement);
```